# plt.imshow works on inverse FFT image but cv2.imwrite dosen't. Any Ideas why?

Tags: python, python-3.x, opencv3.0

Ok, so I have been scratching my head over this for some time now. I took a inverse FFT of an image and I can display it with cv2.imshow just fine.

```
plt.subplot(131), plt.imshow(img_back)
plt.title('Subtracted'), plt.xticks([]), plt.yticks([])
```

[image]

However when I try to save the same image using cv2.imwrite, I get a plain white image. What am I missing ??

```
cv2.imwrite("my_car_preprossed.jpg", img_back)
```

Here are the relevant details of `img_back`

```
img_back.dtype : dtype('float32')
np.finfo(img_back.dtype) : finfo(resolution=1e-06, min=-3.4028235e+38, max=3.4028235e+38, dtype=float32)
img_back.shape = (1944, 2592)
```

Answer (score 0):

So answering my own question. Turns out imwrite only expects values in range [0-255], hence I needed to scale the image to that range. There is no such issue with imshow.

To that end, following did the trick :

1) Divide the final output image(f4 in this case), by the max value found in that image.
2) Multiply it by 255.

```
img_back = img_back / img_back.max()
img_back = img_back * 255
cv2.imwrite("my_img_preprossed.jpg", img_back)
```